# Boto and Python on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to get boto to work, but I am getting an error.

Installed boto via `easy_install`, or simply `python ./setup.py install`

```
cat boto.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2()

3c075474c10b% ./boto.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./boto.py", line 2, in <module>
    import boto
  File "/Users/vasiliyb/scripts/boto.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = boto.connect_ec2()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_ec2'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change the name of your module from "boto.py" to "myboto.py" (or whatever you like) and it will magically work.

You are basically redefining "boto" by naming your module boto.py.

Comment: same issue after renaming the python script to something.py

Comment: problem was that for some reason there was a boto.pyc in the same directory... fixed... thanks